# What is the max buffer size in a portaudio callback?

Tags: c#, f#, portaudio

I’m using [PortAudioSharp](https://gitlab.com/daveyostcom/Bassoon/-/tree/develop/src/Bassoon/PortAudioSharp?ref_type=heads) to get input audio for processing.
The data is delivered to my code
in adaptive-length chunks (`FramesPerBufferUnspecified`)
of unmanaged system memory
via a callback.
Code in a callback must be quick
and must avoid duration-risky behaviors,
such as allocating memory from the heap.

I need to be able to do nontrivial processing in F#/C#.

The callback doesn’t release its chunk explicitly.
Clearly each chunk is guaranteed valid
for the duration of a quick callback,
but how long exactly is it guaranteed valid?

To be as safe as possible
given the constraints and
given the lack of a chunk-lifetime guarantee,
I have to hand off the chunk to my own memory
as quickly as possible.

One idea is for the callback simply to send each chunk to an via a ConcurrentQueue.
There is no guarantee how long a chunk can wait in the queue
before becoming invalid,
so the queue-consuming code
immediately copies the chunk to managed memory
and passes it to an async function for processing.
There is a catch here:
the chunk could become invalid before the agent gets around to making a copy of it.

A safer plan is for the callback
to copy each chunk
into an existing buffer
from a pool.
All buffers are preallocated to the same size,
large enough for the largest possible chunk.

The question is, how big does the buffer size have to be
to cover the maximum possible variable chunk size?
I can’t find any discussion of this in the docs.

Relevant docs:

- The [Stream.cs](https://gitlab.com/daveyostcom/Bassoon/-/blob/develop/src/Bassoon/PortAudioSharp/Stream.cs?ref_type=heads) comment for `public delegate StreamCallbackResult Callback`
- [Writing a Callback Function](https://files.portaudio.com/docs/v19-doxydocs/writing_a_callback.html) – for the underlying C library

Comment: @ross-bencina Could you shed light here?